# How to fetch validation rules with Python's simple_salesforce?

Tags: query, validation-rule, validation, python, simple-salesforce

I want to do something like

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce, format_soql

sf = Salesforce(username=..., password=..., security_token=..., domain=...)
result = sf.query(format_soql("SELECT Id, ValidationName, Active, Description, EntityDefinition.DeveloperName, ErrorDisplayField, ErrorMessage FROM ValidationRule"))
```

to fetch validation rules from Salesforce. The above obviously fails since I cannot query ValidationRules like Account or Contact records. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to use the Tooling API. Support for the Tooling API is relatively minimal in `simple_salesforce`, but it works just fine. Here, you would do

```python
sf.toolingexecute("query?q=SELECT Id, ValidationName, Active, Description, EntityDefinition.DeveloperName, ErrorDisplayField, ErrorMessage FROM ValidationRule")
```